# Nested user-control's controls are null

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I've got a nested user-control hierarchy, and am finding that all the native controls in one of my nested user controls are NULL in its Page_Load event hander.

Here is my layout:

```
Page
    UserControl1
        telerik:RadMultiPage
            telerik:RadGrid
                NestedViewTemplate
                    UserControl2
```

In the UserControl2's Page_Load handler, all native controls are NULL. I'm having trouble working out why. I'm guessing it's something to do with the fact that it's nested inside a grid. Not sure of the best way around this though.

Comment: if you use cache, the control can be null because the cache is direct render the html and not load the controls at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that it was related to my register directive which was added by Resharper.

I've changed:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" Namespace="My.Namespace" Assembly="My.Assembly" %>
```

To the more explicit:

```
<%@ Register src="UserControl2.ascx" tagname="MyUserControl2" tagprefix="uc1" %>
```

And that seems to have fixed it. There's actually many tabs on the page, so perhaps the namespace version of the register wasn't explicit enough, and it was getting confused with controls in another tab.